# Change text but not the icon inside a button

Tags: jquery

I have a `button` with an icon as follows created with bootstrap and font-awesome

```
<button id="btnFavorite" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" onclick="addToFavorites()">
    <i id="imgFavorite" class="fa fa-star"></i>  Favorite
</button>
```

With jQuery I want to update the text "Favorite" without touching the `<i id="imgFavorite" class="fa fa-star"></i>` part.

When I check `$("#btnFavorite").text()`, I get "Favorite", but when I use the `$("#btnFavorite").text("Some value")` this does not only update text but removes `<i id="imgFavorite" class="fa fa-star"></i>` part as well.

I tried `$("Some text").insertAfter("#imgFavorite");` but this does not change the text at all.

How can I just update the text, but keep the icon at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place button text inside **div**:

```
$('body').append("<button id='btnFavorite' class='btn btn-warning pull-right' style='margin-right: 5px;' onclick='addToFavorites()'><i id='imgFavorite' class='fa fa-star'></i> <div class='btn_txt'>Favorite</div> </button>")
```

And **style** accordingly:

```
$('.btn_txt').css('font-size', '20px').css('display', 'inline')
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution indeed does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to just put your button text in a span and select the span instead.

```js
function addToFavorites() {
  $('#btnFavorite span').text('Some value');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button id="btnFavorite" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" onclick="addToFavorites()"><i id="imgFavorite" class="fa fa-star"></i>  <span>Favorite</span></button>
```

---

If you can't edit the HTML and want to only use jQuery, then this is also an option:

```js
function addToFavorites() {
  $('#btnFavorite').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim();
  })[0].textContent = ' Some text';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button id="btnFavorite" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" onclick="addToFavorites()"><i id="imgFavorite" class="fa fa-star"></i>  Favorite</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.text()` will strip the html tags.

Please use `.html()` if you need to manipulate the html.

```
$('#btnFavorite').html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace($(this).text(), 'Some value');
});
```

Comment: Well this will also wipe out the `<i>`. `html()` method replaces all content when used as setter

Comment: that will replace the entire content inside the `<button>`.